# error building phpsh from terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, python

I am following the instructions on the phpsh github page
I navigate to the phpsh directory and run

python setup.py build

and I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 13, in <module>
    p = Popen(["make", "-C", make_dir])
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1228, in _execute_child
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

it seems the files in my python directory actually end in pyo...

not sure what to do about this

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/phpsh

Comment: Have you install Xcode or developer tools (I think make is not in plain OSX)

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal and type `which make` to see that you have minimal compiler tools installed.

If not, download Xcode from the App store and have it install the command line tools.